# Need to group by table but can't find the right way

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

When I try to group the follow query below I get an error like:

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

I have to get a table as invoices by vendor.

```
SELECT 
ia.id, 
COUNT(ia.invoice_id) total_de_facturas,
CASE 
WHEN SUM(ia.invoice_amount) <> 0 
THEN SUM(ia.invoice_amount)
ELSE SUM(ia.base_amount) 
END monto_total,
ia.currency_code tipo_de_moneda,
MIN(ia.invoice_date) Primer_factura, 
MAX(ia.invoice_date) ultima_factura
FROM invoices_all ia
GROUP BY ia.id, ia.invoice_id
ORDER BY total_de_facturas DESC;
```

Actually I fixed the bug Grouping by other column which hasn't got an aggregation function(currency_code). But instead of this one I have to "group by" the table by invoices_id and id,

invoice_date column has dates of invoices,

currency_code column has the exchange rate of the invoice

any suggestion for this trouble?

Comment: Your question is confusing.  The SQL you have posted will not result in an `ORA-00979` error.  Try explaining your data and how you want the result set rows to look.

Comment: Welcome to SO . Read this for posting questions on SO https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
 ia.id, 
 COUNT(ia.invoice_id) AS total_de_facturas,
 SUM(CASE WHEN ia.invoice_amount <> 0 
          THEN ia.invoice_amount
          ELSE ia.base_amount END) AS monto_total,
 ia.currency_code AS tipo_de_moneda,
 MIN(ia.invoice_date) AS Primer_factura, 
 MAX(ia.invoice_date) AS ultima_factura
 FROM invoices_all ia
 GROUP BY ia.id, ia.currency_code
 ORDER BY total_de_facturas DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks, acutally I'm starter and don't understand very well stackoverflow code form

Answer (score 0):

Putting SUM outside of case when should work fine.

```
SELECT IA.ID,
         COUNT (IA.INVOICE_ID) TOTAL_DE_FACTURAS,
         SUM (
            CASE
               WHEN IA.INVOICE_AMOUNT <> 0 THEN IA.INVOICE_AMOUNT
               ELSE IA.BASE_AMOUNT
            END)
            MONTO_TOTAL,
         IA.CURRENCY_CODE TIPO_DE_MONEDA,
         MIN (IA.INVOICE_DATE) PRIMER_FACTURA,
         MAX (IA.INVOICE_DATE) ULTIMA_FACTURA
    FROM INVOICES_ALL IA
GROUP BY IA.ID, IA.CURRENCY_CODE
ORDER BY TOTAL_DE_FACTURAS DESC;
```

If you happened to be need SUM(IA.INVOICE_AMOUNT) comparison then you should first sum it in a sub-query like below.

```
SELECT IA.ID,
         COUNT (IA.INVOICE_ID) TOTAL_DE_FACTURAS,
         SUM (
            CASE
               WHEN IA.SUMMED_INVOICE_AMOUNT <> 0 THEN IA.SUMMED_INVOICE_AMOUNT
               ELSE IA.BASE_AMOUNT
            END)
            MONTO_TOTAL,
         IA.CURRENCY_CODE TIPO_DE_MONEDA,
         MIN (IA.INVOICE_DATE) PRIMER_FACTURA,
         MAX (IA.INVOICE_DATE) ULTIMA_FACTURA
    FROM (  SELECT 
                  SUM (INVOICE_AMOUNT) AS SUMMED_INVOICE_AMOUNT,
                   INVOICE_DATE,
                   CURRENCY_CODE,
                   INVOICE_ID,
                   ID,
                   BASE_AMOUNT
              FROM INVOICES_ALL IA
          GROUP BY INVOICE_DATE,
                   CURRENCY_CODE,
                   INVOICE_ID,
                   ID,
                   BASE_AMOUNT) IA
GROUP BY IA.ID, IA.CURRENCY_CODE
ORDER BY TOTAL_DE_FACTURAS DESC;
```

Comment: Ok, but actually my trouble is that when I tried to group by ID and invoice_id can't do it, how can I solve it?

Comment: But you can. You can put invoice_id in to your group by then it will work. But your results will change ex COUNT(IA.INVOICE_ID) . First you should specify which columns you really have to put into group by.

Comment: I specified it, I need to group by id and invoice_id

Comment: But as i said you can do that. You can put INVOICE_ID into your group by statement without worries. It will cost you its count. Because when you put INVOICE_ID into your group by COUNT(INVOICE_ID) can not count itself.